# Let $a,b,c$ be integers such that
$\gcd(a,6)=3=\gcd(b,6)$. Show that $\gcd(a+b,6)=6$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $a,b,c$ be integers such that
$\gcd(a,6)=3=\gcd(b,6)$.
Show that $\gcd(a+b,6)=6$.

**Attempt:**
Let $d = \gcd(a+b,6)$.
Then, by definition, $d \mid (a+b)$ and $d \mid 6$. It means that $d=1,2,3$ or $6$. On the other hand, we have
$3\mid a$ and $3 \mid b$. Write
$a = 3m$ and $b=3n$ for some integers $m$ and $n$. Then, $a+b=3m+3n=3(m+n)$ and so
$3 \mid (a+b)$. But, $d \mid (a+b)$. Now, $a+b = dp$ for some integer $p$.
Thus, we have $3 \mid dp$ which means $3 \mid d$ or $3 \mid p$.
If $3 \mid d$, then $d=3k$ for some integer $k$. Hence, $d$ is either $3$ or $6$.

But, how to get $d=6$?

Comment: Since $d \mid 6$, then $6=dp$ i.e. $6q=dpq$ and then $6 \mid dpq$ i.e. $6 \mid d$. Is it true?

Comment: If true, then $6\mid d$ and $d \mid 6$ and hence $d=6$.

Comment: Same as in the linked dupe. Similarly, generally $\,(a,2n)=n=(b,2n)\Rightarrow (a+b,2n) = 2n\ \ $

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $\gcd(a,6)=\gcd(b,6)=3$, then $a=3m$ and $b=3n$ for some **odd** $m$ and $n$.

Thus, $a+b=3(m+n)$ while $m+n$ is even, so $6\mid a+b$.

Comment: Ah, i see. $m$ and $n$ must be odd, otherwise, the $\gcd(a,6)$ and $\gcd(b,6)$ are $6$ right?

Comment: that's right, @user795084

Comment: nice correction. thanks

Comment: Since $6 \mid (a+b)$ and $d \mid (a+b)$, then $a+b = 6p$ and $a+b = dq$ for some integers $p$ and $q$. Hence, $6 \mid dq$ i.e. $6\mid d$ or $6 \mid q$. Since $d \mid 6$, then $d=6$ and we are done. Is it true?

Comment: @user795084 Clearly $d \leq 6$. Since $6|a+b$ and $6|6, d = 6$.

Comment: @DerekLuna noted